# Search Result Core Webpart, sort/filter enabled column is not sorting

Tags: search-results, xslt, sorting

I am using sp 2010. I have a search core result webpart on a page. I have modify the xslt in sharepoint designer by a dataview webpart. I have make all columns sort/filter enabled.

Filtering is working. But sorting is not working.

Is this a known issue? How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Here is a printscreen. I have make all columns sort/filter enabled.

[image]
[image]

When I click on "Ascending" or "Descending" the results are the same. It is not working.

Comment: you mean you have sort dropdown? Can you please share a screesnhot

Comment: See updated information inclusive printscreen.

Comment: this looks more of a DataViewWebpart than a Core Results search webpart.. Please check if you have sorting enabled in the xsl this link http://sympmarc.com/2008/12/16/sorting-displays-in-data-view-web-parts/

Comment: no this is a search result core webpart. I only modified the xslt for the presentation of the columns.

Comment: I see here they are talking about bindings. I do not add the bindings to the search core webpart! Is this the issue? Where can I add the bindings? http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/02/26/customizing-search-results-sharepoint-2010-people-search-results-custom-sorting-using-xslt/